# WooCommerce: Change cart total sent to payment Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the cart total at checkout, I have a completely valid use case for this, basically Paypal doesn't support my local currency.

So instead, I leave the store currency as USD, but enter the prices as if they were my local currency, and on the checkout page I inform the customers(all local) that they will be billed in USD and i show them the converted amount.

[image]

The issue is that the Total being sent to the Gateway (Paypal) is **not** $16.65, instead it sends the $45.00

Here's the code and hook I used before to get this working before:

```
function uv_set_total_for_gateway( object $order, array $order_data ) : void {

    $total = $order->get_total();

    // Convert our total to the what we want to pass to the Payment gateway
    $converted_total = $total * 0.37; 
    $converted_total = round( $converted_total, 2 );

    // Set the new calculated total for processing by the payment gateway
    $order->set_total( $converted_total );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'uv_set_total_for_gateway', 9999, 2 );
```

I'm not sure why this no longer works

Comment: Is there additional code? Testing locally with COD it doesn't display or affect anything till the order is created.

Comment: @MarkTruitt That's exactly the issue, but this needs to work with payment gateways like Paypal. I want the total sent to Paypal to be the converted amount. Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/UVLabs/set-wc-payment-gateway-currency